# Obj-C - Filter multiple keys by text in searchbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I'm trying to filter two keys with the text in my search bar. See my code below so far, but it crashes my app.

```
NSSet *keys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"node_title", @"address", nil];

self.filteredStores = [self.storesData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@", keys, self.searchBar.text]];
```

I feel like I'm on the right track, but I'm unable to do this successfully. Help is appreciated!

Comment: `key` doesn't exist in `@"node_title"` nor `@"address"`. Use `SELF`. It's even in the sample of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsset/1416324- But it's unclear the link between `keys`, and `sortesData` (what's that? What are the objects populating it?). Could you explain it really?

Comment: @"node_title" and @"address" are my keys in self.storesData. I'm trying to search those keys for what's in self.searchBar.text. The link you posted is broken :) @Larme

Comment: And why is `keys` a `NSSet`? Why not just `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@ OR %K contains[c] %@",@"node_title", self.searchBar.text, @"address", self.searchBar.text]`?

Comment: Ahh thank you! Works perfectly. @Larme For some reason I thought using NSSet would be cleaner. Attempted the above way initially but I think I was just writing the line incorrectly because it didnt work previously :/ Appreciate your help!!

Comment: If you still want want a NSSet of keys, see DonMag answer. I'd recommend still to use `NSCompoundPredicate`.

Answer (score 1):

One option...

```
NSSet *keys = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"node_title", @"address", nil];

NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *k in keys) {
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@", k, self.searchBar.text];
    [subpredicates addObject:p];
}

NSPredicate *final = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];

self.filteredStores = [self.storesData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:final];
```